# How can I fix error 404 when publishing my github page?

Tags: http-status-code-404, github-pages

Could someone please help me to publish my website on github?

I created a repository where I uploaded all my files. Then published it. However, when I go to my URL, I get an error 404 - please see here https://camielalli.github.io/.

This is my repository: https://github.com/camielalli/camielalli.github.io

I'm a complete beginner with github and creating a website, so I'm sure there's something very obvious that I'm missing out on.

Thanks ever so much for anyone who will help me :)

Comment: Did you read the error message? "For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file."

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was easier than I thought :)